# how to change the master and detail in UISplitViewController - iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I created an application in which I have a UISpliеViewController, also the master section has a tabbar. In the tabbar I have three controllers. When I click on the second item tabbar in portrait orientation, I have a controller called News. But when I'm in the horizontal position, I want the master section to open the controller that is on the tabbar item1, and the detail must have the News tab.

I read and think that I need to use:

```
func primaryViewController (forExpanding splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? or 
func splitViewController (_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, on primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Pain
```

, but I do not understand how to organize it